# Grouping several types of shapefiles into one layer being able to turn on/off

Tags: qgis, openlayers, qgis2web, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I am wondering if QGIS (or qgis2web) can realize this: I have various shapefiles (label as points and lines) and I want to categorize them into one single layer which can be turned on and off. (It needs to have a blue tick-box in front of the top hierarchy).

Plus, there is another strange exporting issue. That is: Grouped layer will be automatically placed to the bottom layer regardless where you put it when editing. Then I need to manually modify the js code in layers.js.

Please see the example:
"I would like to have a blue tick-box for ROAD grouped layer"

1. output on web
   [image]
2. QGIS editing panel
   [image]

This is what I expect to realize:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make one checkbox that shows multiple layers in QGIS or qgis2web?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177173/how-to-make-one-checkbox-that-shows-multiple-layers-in-qgis-or-qgis2web)

Comment: Hi @GreyHippo I found out that the latest version of qgis2web plugin will fix this issue thanks! :)